# Smarty issues with Fckediter

Tags: smarty, fckeditor

I'm new to this forum , i  hope u do not mind questions even if its stupid.

i m trying to post a value from the fckeditor embedded in smarty template.The value submitted is,

```
    a
    b
    c
    d
```

however when echo the posted value i get ,

```
a b c d
```

which is very irritating because i want the actual value submitted.
No matter whatever i do  i only see text with these

tags i do not understand if have to do any configuration in smarty or fckeditor or what ?

Please help with this any help will be greatly appreciated.

i will appreciate your help

Mukesh ?

Comment: Please post some actual code to illustrate your problem.

Comment: please some one ? pekka if still not clear please let me know

Comment: Can you post what the HTML source code looks like in FCKEditor? Can you show how you echo the posted value?

Comment: btw, you can add a @pekka to comments so they reach me straight away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just that my framework used was sanitizing all GET,POST requests.
Then removed those function that was causing the function and job done .

function sanitize($data)
{

```
$data = trim(strip_tags($data, "<a><b><strong><em><i><u><br><h3><h4><h5>"));
return $data;
```

}